# Problem to show custom post type in archive page category wise

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, pre-get-posts

I was facing problem to show custom post type post category wise. Then i found to solve the problem .  i wrote below code in function page :

```
function my_blog_category( $query ) {
if ( is_post_type_archive( 'blog') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $action =   (isset($_REQUEST['ac'])) ? $_REQUEST['ac'] : 'none';
    if($action!='none') $query->set( 'category_name', $action );
    }
 }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_blog_category' );
```

So when I click

> local/wp/index.php/blog?ac=company-news

it shows all company-new category's post. But main problem is that I upload all file to website server. Now filter is not working on my webserver. There I click

> Mydomain/index.php/blog?ac=company-news

it show all post, not filter by category. I don't why it not work on my live web server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the information that their is in action variable.

```
$action =   (isset($_REQUEST['ac'])) ? $_REQUEST['ac'] : 'none';
var_dump("action: "+$action);
```

With this line, you will be able to review it's content and you will see that you don't get the correct information.
I guess that your dev database is out off synch with your local one.

So, you need to create post/page/categories to review your code.
[Otherwise, I'm using a really nice plug-in to migrate your local to dev DB.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)

Note: don't forget to push your uploads too =)

Comment: Dear, I check deeply i found some different my local and webserver. I notice on my local webserver Blog and post are category name is 'Categories' but on my webserver there category name is 'Category', on my custom post type and original post type both show category name is 'category', i think this is problem. How can i change name as 'Categories'

Comment: As your are using a plug-in to create CPT, it's a database issue (Otherwise, your local code will be the same as your dev server and work correctly). What you soulld do that will resolve the issue, simply migrate your local db to your dev server. You can use a plug-in called migrate db